# access the certain field in a DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox, each

I have this html output:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
  <td>Value 1</td>
</tr>
```

I want to check if the checkbox is marked as `checked` and then access the second `td` to get `"Value 1"`

I've tried something like this:

```
$( "tr td input[type=checkbox]" ).each(function( index ) {
     if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          alert($(this).parent().eq(1).text());
        }
});
```

and

```
var checkValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().text();
}).get();
```

For both of those examples I get an empty output. 
Any ideas of what went wrong in here? I would appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent()` is the `td`, you need to get the next sibling

```
var checkValues = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().next().text();
}).get();
```

or

```
$("tr td input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function (index) {
    alert($(this).parent().next().text());
});
```

Comment: thank you, this will work! I need 10 min to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `closest` to the nearest `tr` and `find` the second `td`:

```
$("tr td input[type=checkbox]").each(function( index ) {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());
    }
});
```

Or you can go to the `parent` `td` and use `next`:

```
alert($(this).parent().next().text());
```

It should be noted that the second method will break should your DOM structure change, whilst the first is more robust to changes.